# C# Get subclass attribute value

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to make this:

```
class A { 
   //attibutes
}

class B : A {
   public int classBAttribute = 5;
   // other attributes and methods
}
```

My question is this if I have an instance of A class how can i get the instance of the B class or access his attributes?

```
B b = new B();
Application.Add(b);

//other form
A a = Application.GetA();
B b = getBFromA(a);// ???  Note:  B b = a as B; does't work i tried
```

Comment: Well. You can't upcast an A to a B. Simple.

Comment: Also, for future reference - what you are referring to as attributes are called class members. Attributes, in the .NET language, is something completely different. =)

Comment: Well i don't know right te concepts i'm more a algorithm guy :)

Comment: Which is why I'm pointing it out for **future** reference. I wasn't chiding. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this -- there is no magical way to create derived objects from base objects in general.

To enable such a scheme class `B` would need to define a constructor that accepts an `A` argument:

```
public B(A a)
{
    // do whatever makes sense to create a B from an A
}
```

which you can then use as

```
var b = new B(a);
```

Of course after this `a` and `b` will be completely different objects; changing one will not affect the other.

You should also get the terminology right in order to avoid confusion: `classBAttribute` is not an [attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0w1kczw.aspx), it is a [field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173118.aspx).

Comment: Well i guess i have to use a database because i can't get B from A without a database.Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is this if I have an instance of A class how can i get the
>   instance of the B class or access his attributes?

How would your program know an instance of A is actually of type B?

An instance of B could be used as A (as B is a specialization of A), but the opposite is not possible.

Comment: That's why i asked to know if it was possible :). Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don't fully understand the question or the answers, but...

Casting an `A` to a `B` **should** work (as long as the `A` is actually (also) a `B`).

```
A a = Application.GetA();
if(a is B)
{
    B b = (B)a;
    DoSomething(b.classBAttribute);
}
else
{
    // TODO: Some fallback strategy or exception (?)
}
```

Comment: I tried to cast him didn't work the custom field of B are not inherited from A

Comment: @AntonioPapa Once you have cast the object to B you have access to the field. What does "didn't work" mean?

Comment: It means that b is null

Comment: that value returns when i cast a to b